# How to switch two rows in a dataset in R to match up with diel designations

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am working with a large data set with diel times and I am wondering how I would switch the Day and Night (see screenshot) so they line up with the rest of the Day/Nights. There are multiple instances for this throughout the dataset. For context, I am trying to lag1 the depths and having these 'backwards' so to speak does not work. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? (A loop?).

So it would look like this instead (pulling just the light and hour here for simplicity in the example):

```
Light  Hour
Night 5
Night 6
Night 7
Day   7
Day   8
Day   9
```

I tried ordering it using Light too but that doesn't seem to work.
Thank you!

[image: Screenshot of dataset]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to change the order of rows using `dplyr::arrange`

```r
library(dplyr)


df
#>    light hour
#> 1  Night    1
#> 2  Night    2
#> 3    Day    1
#> 4  Night    3
#> 5    Day    2
#> 6    Day    3
#> 7    Day    4
#> 8  Night    4
#> 9    Day    5
#> 10   Day    6
#> 11 Night    5
#> 12   Day    7
#> 13 Night    6
#> 14   Day    8
#> 15 Night    7
#> 16 Night    8

df %>%
  arrange(desc(light), hour)
#>    light hour
#> 1  Night    1
#> 2  Night    2
#> 3  Night    3
#> 4  Night    4
#> 5  Night    5
#> 6  Night    6
#> 7  Night    7
#> 8  Night    8
#> 9    Day    1
#> 10   Day    2
#> 11   Day    3
#> 12   Day    4
#> 13   Day    5
#> 14   Day    6
#> 15   Day    7
#> 16   Day    8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, sorry that didn't work. I need to switch just those day/night '7' rows so they are lined up with the other 'day/night' rows and keep everything else the same. I have already tried the basic ordering functions. I assume I need to use a loop to iterate over the ~100 instances there are of the same thing throughout the dataset, but I don't know how to do that